# What is the relationship between the following PayPal products?

Tags: paypal

PayPal has a complicated naming strategy for its payments products, but it appears that some of them share common building blocks. How are the following product brands related, and what are their histories?

These three appear to be the latest offerings:

- PayPal Payments Standard
- PayPal Payments Advanced
- PayPal Payments Pro
- PayPal Payments Pro (PayFlow Edition)

These two appear to be deprecated or on their way out:

- Website Payments Standard
- Website Payments Pro

The above products have documentation that seem to reference "PayFlow" products frequently:

- PayPal Payflow Link
- PayPal Payflow Pro

This seems to be the underpinning of some, but not all, of the above products, and these two may in fact be the same product:

- PayPal Payment Gateway
- Payflow Payment Gateway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer the following blog (recently written) which explains in great detail about the PayPal API and products

http://whyidentity.blogspot.in/2012/09/paypal-apis-galaxy-not-so-far-away.html

Please let us know if you need further details

Comment: Yes, that is an excellent blog post. Unfortunately you forgot to include your transparent-redirect based PCI compliant offering though (PayPal Payments Pro 2.0 w/Transparent Redirect).

Comment: Also, it would be nice to have the difference between x.com and paypal.com described!

Comment: Link to article is currently broken.

Comment: Please refer the new URL will update the answer also http://whyidentity.blogspot.in/2012/09/paypal-apis-galaxy-not-so-far-away.html